# Making a contour map in matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, latitude-longitude, contour

I have a .csv file in which is included one column with Latitudes, one column with Longitudes and one column with Values(for example 1,2,3, etc). I would like to create a map but I don't know which command to use.
Could anyone help me to make it?

[image]

Comment: Look for `contour`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **griddata()** if your data is not gridded
Use **contourf** to create filled contours